# sorting after “group by” in a SharePoint Online list problem

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, view, grouping, ordering

I have a problem saving after sorting on a list grouped by number ID. I cant order the group permanently.

[image: Correct order]

but when a save the view it goes back to the default order:

[image: how it ends up]

What can be done to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please following steps:**

1.Sign in the list as an admin >> **List settings**

2.On the List Settings page, scroll to **Views** section and click on the specific view

3.On the Edit View page, scroll to **Sort** section, please set sort by the column

[image]

[image]

[image]